# Execute Python with pygtk without terminal appear

Tags: python, terminal, pygtk

I have a little issue using pygtk, i have this project written in python, now the program works correctly, i have already added the string for the execution using terminal:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
```

Now i want to know how to exec this script hiding the terminal that pop out once you double click the file.

Anyone knows?

Comment: What OS are you interested in?

Comment: i am interested in Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving it as a .pyc and executing that one.

Take a look at [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/py_compile.html) and [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/compileall.html).

Basically this:

```
import py_compile
py_compile.compile('abc.py')
```

Comment: I'm don't have access to a linux box to test it right now but I'm pretty sure that has solved it before.

Comment: executing the .pyc pop up an alert window: "No Such program installed for the <<Bytecode Python>> file"

Comment: It works! i choose the python interpreter to open the bytecode python file and now it run with a double click, Thanks!

Comment: @PhantomFav No prob :) Great to hear!!